# openCV - white color filter

Tags: c++, opencv

I'd like to generate some kind of color filter method that is able to filter a specific color - in my case the WHITE color.

This is what I've got so far but tbh I'm sure if this is the right way.

*(c++ myfile.mm)*

```
static Mat whiteFilter(cv::Mat img) {
    cv::Mat temp;
    cv::cvtColor(img, temp, CV_RGB2HSV);
    cv::Scalar  lower(0, 0, 0),
                higher(180, 255, 255);
    cv::inRange( temp, lower, higher, img);
    return img;
}
```

... because of these results:

[image: Input image]

[image: Output image]

How to edit the function & the values to achieve a way better WHITE-color extraction?

Comment: Also found this question during my research. @Miki. But I'd like to get answers how to edit my code (C++) instead of the python code you linked. So please remove the duplicate marker!

Comment: I can't post an answer but have a look into [thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html)

Comment: You just need to change your range: `cv::Scalar  lower(0, 0, 230), higher(180, 25, 255);` as explained in the duplicate

Comment: 1) Don't spam tags! 2) We are not a coding service. 3) You should not have skipped the mandatory [tour]. 4) Also read [ask] to see how you can improve your question..